# Using text field to retrieve date from excel

Tags: java, excel, textfield

1. The error here shows that the data type criteria mismatch
2. Please tell how to filter the date using two text fields
3. The error at dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY").parse(G); shows that no method found for parse (Date)

   ```
   String a=jTextField1.getText();
   String b=jTextField2.getText();

   Date n=new Date();
   SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");

   DefaultTableModel tm=(DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();

   try 
   {
       Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
       Connection con;
       con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:odbc:NAMT","Navi","1234");
       PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(
       "select * from [Sheet1$] where SEVERITY='Critical' and DATE BETWEEN '"+a+"'and'"+b+"'" );

       try (ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery()) 
       {    
           while(rs.next())
           {
               String B=rs.getString("NetworkElement");
               String E=rs.getString("Severity");
               java.util.Date G = rs.getDate("DATE"); 
               java.util.Date dateFormat;
               dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY").parse(G);
               tm.addRow(new Object[] {B,E,G});
           }
       }
       con.close();
   }
   catch(Exception x)
   {
       System.out.println(x); 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SimpleDateFormat.parse()
```

expects a String, not a Date.

```
 SimpleDateFormat.fomat()
```

takes a Date-Object.

Comment: 1. In my Excel the date is saved as mm/dd/yyyy. how can i just retrieve that data using a text field. please helpme.

Comment: Sorry I was ill and a few days away from the SO. I'm not sure if I understand what you want to do: you've got two textfields (in a swing application) and want to get results from a database? What does the dates in your textfields look like? And what error do you get right now?